# getting specific filename from bash

Tags: mysql, regex, bash, perl

So I have a perl module that uses a bash command to obtain the file(s) with certain "table" names. In my specific case, it is looking for tables with the name "event", but I need this to work with all names too.

Currently, I have the following code in my perl script to obtain MYI files with the name table, and I am receiving not only `event_*` but also `event_extra_data_*` as well. For my example, I only need the 2nd table that exists in my database for event_. As my test info, I have, currently,

```
event_1459161160_0
event_1459182760_0
event_extra_data_1459182745_0
event_extra_data_1459182760_0
```

which are partitioned tables from tables "event" and event_extra_data which is the value that the `$table` variable sees below.

Anyways, my question is, how do i limit this to only receiving `event_1459182760_0.MYI` and not `event_extra_data_1459182760_0.MYI` which it is currently getting?

```
elsif ($sql =~ /\{LAST\}/i )
{
    $cmd  = 'ls -1 /var/lib/mysql/sfsnort/'.$table.'_*MYI | grep -v template | tail -n1 | cut -d"/" -f6 | cut -d"." -f1';
    $value = `$cmd`;
    print "Search Value: $value\n";
    if ($value eq "")
    {
        $sql = ""; # same as with FIRST
    }
    else
    {
        $sql =~ s/\{LAST\}/$value/g;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered doing it all in perl, say with [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Don't parse `ls` - there's no point, and it's prone to causing problems.

I would point out this - the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function within perl allows you to do to a limited number of "regex-like" patterns. (Note - they *aren't* regex, so don't get them mixed up).

```
foreach my $filename ( glob "event_[0-9]*" ) { 
     #do something with $filename
}
```

If you're just after the last - when sorted numerically:

```
my ( $last ) = reverse sort glob "event_[0-9]*";
```

Given you have a single path, then you should be able to:

```
my ( $last ) = reverse sort glob "/var/lib/mysql/sfsnort/event_[0-9]*.MYI";
```

Note - that this works, assuming you're working with `time()` numeric values - it's doing an alphanumeric sort (and on directory names too).

If that isn't a valid assumption, you'll need a custom sort - which is quite easy, you can feed sort a subroutine to sort by.

Either:

```
sort { my ($a1) = $a =~ /(\d+)/; my ($b1) = $b =~ /(\d+)/; $b1 <=> $a1 }
```

To extract the first 'string of digits' from the path. (note - also includes directories).

Or use the `-M` [file test](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html):

```
sort { -M $a <=> -M $b }
```

Which will read modification time from the file (technically `-M` is age in days).

You can remove the `reverse` if you custom sort, just by swapping `$a` and `$b`.

Answer (score 0):

Though I think this would be better done all in perl, to answer your specific question about how to get `event_*` but not `event_extra*`, you could of course add that to your `grep` to filter out, or you could use a different glob, like `$table_[0-9]*` if there's always an `_` then a digit after the table name.

In perl you could do it something like the following though:

```perl
opendir( DIR, '/var/lib/mysql/sfsnort/' );
my @files = sort grep { /$table_\d/ } readdir( DIR );
closedir( DIR );

$files[$#files] =~ /(^[^.]+)/;
my $value = $1;
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. one question though, im kindve a perl noob, so what exactly does the $#files mean? Ive only used # for comments so far, and google searches for symbolic operators kinda suck.

Comment: With an array `$#<name>` will get the last index used in the array, so in this case `$files[$#files]` will get the value at the last index in the `@files` array